# SSMS Error when creating database "Method not found .. StringCollection"

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2016.
When I try to create a local database by right clicking on Databases and selecting "New Database" I get the following error:

[image]

I've tried restarting SSMS and the machine.

I can create the database through SQL, however I get the same error when trying to launch any GUI dialogs for the database. So creating it thru SQL doesn't work around my issue as I need to configure it also (and I don't want to write scripts for everything).

Comment: What is you net framework version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

- Make sure SSMS 2016 has the latest fixes for that version. Many people forget that tools need patching as well as server components. See [Latest Builds of Management Studio](https://blogs.sentryone.com/team-posts/latest-builds-management-studio/) for more information.
- Consider updating SSMS to [the latest major version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), which is 17.2 at the time of writing. From that link:

  > This version of SSMS works with all supported versions of SQL Server 2008 - SQL Server 2017 and provides the greatest level of support for working with the latest cloud features in Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Data Warehouse.
- Perform an uninstall and reinstall. You could reinstall the same version if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The method "System.collections.specialized.stringCollection " is part of Microsoft .NET Framework classes.

[image: Net Framework Class]

According to the Microsoft documentation [Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server), SQL Server 2016 requires .NET 4.6.1 to be installed.

As the error references a missing method after applying the SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU3) patch, it is likely there is a .NET framework patch as well.  A possible solution to try would be to first create a system restore point, just in case this does not work or causes other unforeseen issues.  Then run Windows updates.  If any patches for .NET Framework appear, try installing those updates.  Sometimes system reboots are needed for updates to complete.  Reboot your system after installation is complete.